# Removing repeating values from cells

Tags: excel

The numbers I have in cells sometimes repeat.

For example:

[image]

I'd like every number to be shown once, removing the duplicates.
Is there a formula to do this easily? without using several helper cells, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Excel 356.

Select a portion of a **single row** and run this short macro:

```
Sub rm_dups()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        arr = .Unique(rng.Value, True)
    End With
    
    rng.Clear
    rng.Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]